# nodejs for angular server-side rendering and apache, php for API

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I've setted server-site rendering for Angular 4, so know I can run nodejs server and move to http://localhost:3000.

By the other hand, I have apache2 and server API writting in PHP on "http://localhost/request".

How can I organise my server to redirect all users to nodejs and allow Angular's services call API (apache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write rules in your Apache "vhost.conf" config file for your two entities, the angular project and php api project